# Poetry does not recognize supplemental source

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a package `my-package` that requires a supplemental source that points to a non pypi URL. The following is in the `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "custom"
url = "https://url/simple"
priority = "supplemental"
```

I am able to build the package without any errors.

However, when I try to `poetry add my-package` in a different repo `my-repo`, I get the following error

`Repository "custom" does not exist.`

and I am unable to install or add `my-package`. I have tried pointing to the `.whl` file as well and the python package that needs the "custom" source always throws an error.

I can get around this issue by defining the "custom" URL as a "supplemental" source in the `pyproject.toml` of `my-repo` but this seems redundant and incorrect. If `my-repo` needs `my-package`, then it should be able to read the supplemental source defined in the `my-package` `pyproject.toml` file. Ideally I would define "custom" repo in ONE repository (`my-package`). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is an open issue in poetry https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4659. There was no fix on it yet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue, I asked the poetry developers, they said there is no other way. Here is the link to my issue: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/8973

Comment: Welcome. Are you posting an answer? If yes, please elaborate, here, with the link only as supporting material. See [answer] for guidance. Otherwise, please turn this into a comment once you(ve gotten commenting privilege (50 rep). Until then rather focus on questions you could answer fully.

Answer (score 0):

Poetry intentionally does not inherit the `tool.poetry.source` from dependencies. It seemed like an oversight at a first glance, but it actually makes sense.

Imagine you write package `C` that depends on both packages `A` and `B`. Both package `A` and `B` define a source with the same name, but with different urls. It's unclear which one `C` should inherit.

More info in this thread: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4659